# How is "questions per day" calculated?

Tags: discussion, support

As of today (26th Jan. 2016) the [statistics page for Portuguese SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language) shows that we have 1.2 questions/day (and we should work on that!). The same page says that we are in day 195 of our beta. The [questions page](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions) shows that we have 622 questions. Using basic math our questions/day statistic should be 3.17 (622 questions divided by 196 days), but the *official* result is almost 3 times lower. I know 3.17 questions per day is far from 10 (considered to be good for a healthy beta), but is much better than 1.2!

How exactly is calculated the questions/day? Is this behavior a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After following the link provided on [Jorge B.'s answer](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/221/163) I came across [this official answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/5887)(asked on Meta.ServerFault SE). It states that:

```
Questions per day = (# of new questions over last 14 days) / 14
```

If you mouse hover over the box with the number of questions per day it clearly says: *1.2 questions per day on average over the past 2 weeks.*

Answer (score 3):

[jmac♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/209637/jmac) unofficial answer [How are the "questions per day" calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200252/how-are-the-questions-per-day-calculated)

---

## What [the Stats Say](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users)

[image: Questions per Day]

We want to find a number matching 7,176 questions per day over the past two weeks.

## Simple Search

I searched for all questions created in the past two weeks (October 1st through October 14th) with [this simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2013-10-1..2013-10-14).

This returns 100,489 questions.

Dividing by 14 to get the daily answer, we get 7,177.786/day, which is 2/day above our target.

If we extend the search [to October 15th](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2013-10-1..2013-10-15) we get 100,988 posts.

## Conjecture

The calculation is not for full days, but for hours. Rather than searching by day, it is likely searching for posts made over the past 336 hours.

Since the standard search does not include deleted posts, chances are that deleted posts are excluded.

I believe Migrated posts are also excluded as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think "questions per day" is something like a one-week or two-week average. (If you're interested in the precise number, you can take 10 minutes to count the questions yourself, or take 15 minutes to write a nice question on Meta.SE, or both...)

In the first few days/weeks we had many question. The point of only taking a relatively short period of time into account is that it better reflects the *current* activity on the site, i.e. how many questions we can expect *tomorrow*. 1.2 questions is a much better guess than 3.2 questions.